# When to load data in UITableViewController?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am currently loading data coming from a `JSON` service in the `viewDidLoad` method in `UITableViewController`. The problem is that is the data takes time to be retrieved and parsed, the view takes time to be created.
Where is the best place to load this data? I assume that there is a hook somewhere to load data after the view is created. By doing this I will be able to use some `UIActivityIndicatorView` in the final view.
Thanks

Answer (score 6):

Finally here is a solution based on comments: Launch a thread in viewDidLoad to get data without blocking all:

```
- (void) viewDidLoad
{
    dataLoaded = NO;

    [self initSpinner];
    [self launchLoadData];
...
}

-(void)launchLoadData {
    NSLog(@"Launching thread");
    [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(loadData) toTarget:self withObject:nil];
}

- (void) loadData {
    dataLoaded = NO;
    NSLog(@" thread launched");
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    [self loadDataFromURL:nil];
    dataLoaded = YES;
    [self.tableView reloadData];
    [pool release];
}

- (void)loadDataFromURL:(NSString*)url {
    // start the spinner to show that loading may be time consuming...
    [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector: @selector(spinBegin) toTarget:self withObject:nil];
    JSONLoader *loader = [[JSONLoader alloc] init];
    self.accounts = [loader getAccountsFromURL:@"http://foo/bar/repository.json"];
    [loader release];
    //[NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:3];
    [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector: @selector(spinEnd) toTarget:self withObject:nil];
}
```

and use the flag to display or not data in table. tableView reloadData will do the rest when called from thread.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (dataLoaded) return [self.accounts count];
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're trying to ask is the workflow for displaying data from a web service in a UITableView.

Here's what I recommend:

- Your `viewDidLoad` makes a `NSURLRequest` for your JSON file. Also
  adds a loading view to the current view (I use a `UIView` with a
  black bg (0.5 alpha), plus a label and UIActivityIndicator). In this
  method you also set a BOOL ivar (which you need to add in your
  header) called `loaded` to NO.
- You concat your `NSURLRequest` data as it comes down into a mutable
  data object.
- When your `NSURLRequest` finishes, you turn it's data into a string,
  and parse the JSON into an array of some sort (or dictionary if you
  want). In the same method you remove the loading view, and change
  your boolean `loaded` to YES. You then tell the tableView to reload
  it's data: `[self.tableView reloadData];`

Here's where the magic happens... in your table view methods

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (loaded) return [myArrayOfJSONObjects count];
    return 0; // Will only return 0 if the data is not downloaded
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    // Configure the cell...
    if (loaded) {
        cell.textLabel.text = [myArrayOfParsedJSONObjects objectAtIndex:row];
        //Anything else you want to set
    }
    else {
        //Do nothing :) - you shouldn't reach this else anyway because your numberOfRows method should stop it
    }
}
```

Comment: Not exactly. THis is what I already do. I load data on viewDidLoad and populate the table in cellForRowAtIndexPath. It works but what I said is that in this case, if the JSON service takes 10 seconds to reply, the view appears 10 seconds after the user selected it. In my case, the view is loaded from another table view when the user clicked on a row.

Comment: So are you asking is there a place you can load it before?

Comment: I can load it anywhere of course but what I want to do is: 1/ display the view (potentially empty table) 2/ automatically load the data from the remote service 2'/ display some wait message while loading

Answer (score 0):

*You can open new view and show UIActivityIndicator with message for user, what you loading fresh data for him.*

As for me, this is best choice, because interface remains responsible and user see what you actually do something and app not hanged.

Comment: i open a new view with message in which case i stop this loader [tableview reloadData]